# Reading a BLOB that is appended to HTTP extension using C#

Tags: c#, ajax, http, blob, asp.net-ajax

So I am using a third-party service that lets me edit my `XML` file that is stored on the server path. Now once I am done editing my `XML`, I save the file to local memory storage that generates a BLOB appended to a URL.

Example:

```
blob:http://localhost/0e06af7a-a1a9-4bf1-a79a-78a1e107648f
```

Where the `0e06af7a-a1a9-4bf1-a79a-78a1e107648f` is the token created for the current edit. Now when I run the above URL in a browser, I can see:

[image]

My question is: How can I read the above URL using C# and then save the content to an object that I can later use to upload to a file or a cloud. I have tried using the `WebClient`:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
Stream stream = client.OpenRead("blob:http://localhost/0e06af7a-a1a9-4bf1-a79a-78a1e107648f");
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
string str= reader.ReadToEnd();
```

But it gives me an error saying that the `URL` is not correct and should start with `HTTP` or `HTTPS`.

Edit: I am able to save the blob to a file using JQuery:

```
var download = $('<a>Download ' + "file.xml" + '</a>').attr("href", "blob:http://localhost/0e06af7a-a1a9-4bf1-a79a-78a1e107648f");
download.attr("download", "file.xml");
```

This successfully creates a file called `file.xml` and downloads the file. I am looking to save this blob content on the server side so I can send it to a `Amazon S3` bucket.

Again Editing:

So, currently I have saved the `XML` as a string and I am trying to send it to the C# Controller via AJAX but running into the 500 internal server error.

```
        var xmlString = self.xml2Str(self.xmlState.xml);
        //console.log(xmlString);
        var blob = new Blob([xmlString], { type: "text/xml" }); 
        console.log(blob);
        var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        console.log(url);
        var json = {
            xmlString: xmlString
        };

        var test = JSON.stringify(json);
        console.log(test);

        try {
            $.ajax({
                url: BaseURL + "Home/SendXMLToS3",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { "json": test},
                type: "POST",
                success: function (data) {
                    //TODO: Add whatever if you want to pass a notification back
                    alert("Done");
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    //TODO: Add some code here for error handling or notifications
                    alert("Not Done");
                }
            });
        }
        catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
```

The contents of `test` variable are as follows (from the console):

```
{"xmlString":"<nitf>\n  <head>\n    <docdata>\n      <identified-content>\n        <classifier id=\"box-geometry\" value=\"147,623,250,790\" />\n        <classifier id=\"uuid\" value=\"Mv8XVAViEeqyc3SUunSxMg\" />\n      </identified-content>\n    </docdata>\n  </head>\n  <body>\n    <body.head />\n    <body.content>\n      <p>\n        <lang fontStyle=\"regular\" style=\".Bodylaser\">How is this different from Pegasus?</lang>\n      </p>\n      <p>\n        <lang fontStyle=\"regular\" style=\".Bodylaser\">Pegasus could be installed on your phone without your knowledge through just a missed WhatsApp video call. In the case of the new breach, a user has to manually download the MP4 file sent to them before any malicious code can be run. The problem is not with WhatsApp’s end-to-end encryption feature here. Getting remote access to your phone is the equivalent of actually holding it in one’s hand. End-to-end encryption is meant to stop attackers from stealing or snooping on chats in between. So, unless someone has access to your device, they can’t actually read your chats, even if they intercept them.</lang>\n      </p>\n    </body.content>\n  </body>\n</nitf>"}
```

Also tried setting the default ASP.NET has request validation enabled by default to help protect against XSS to false.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult SendXMLToS3(string json)
```

Still the same 500 error persists: `jquery.min.js:4 POST http://localhost/DEGit/Home/SendXMLToS3 500 (Internal Server Error)` in the `h.send(c.hasContent&&c.data||null)` method.

How can I:

1. Read the generated `blob` URL content in C#?
2. Send the `test` string via AJAX to C#?
3. Anything else that you guys can suggest.

Thanks

Comment: What happens when you remove that "blob:", leaving just "http://..."?

Comment: @HansKeﬆing The URL is not found. It is basically a in-memory blob that is created during run time and destroyed as soon as the process is complete. I managed to send this URL to my Controller to be processed but I am not sure how to read the contents from this

Comment: You do not have XML, it is HTML.  You cannot read HTML with XML methods.  HTML and XML are similar and only some HTML will read with XML tools.

Comment: @jdweng Not true, the XML is serialized and appended to this URL. It is something like serializing a XML and saving it to a file. In this case, the method appends the blob to a in-memory URL

Comment: You jquery runs in the browser, where the C# code runs on the server. So the localhost points to a different machine. Can you load the (contents of the) xml using JQuery, and then post that to the server?

Comment: @GvS That is what I am trying sir but getting a 500 error at the moment when sending via AJAX to C# Controller. Please see updated edit to the question. Thanks

Comment: Then where is the XML Ident (first line of an xml)?

Comment: @jdweng Sir, I am using these two method: `var blob = new Blob([xmlString], { type: "text/xml" });` which creates a blob type for my `xmlString` that I posted in my edited question and then I am creating a url via this method: `var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);`. I have also verified that my blob is created as XML only: `Blob {size: 1131, type: "text/xml"}
size: 1131
type: "text/xml"
__proto__: Blob`

Comment: Regarding the 500 error, its server side error, in your case its aws s3, check s3 docs on how to upload file using ajax. in case your server not s3 then check the server docs.

Comment: @jawad I am not able to hit my Controller method so I guess your suggestion is out of this question (at the moment). If I am able to get this blob or string to my Controller method, then I can proceed ahead with the uploading process.

Comment: In that case, share enough code so that we can test and debug the issue, otherwise create fresh project with the controller code and try hitting it with simple request using curl,postman,.net and increase the variables one by one till you figure out the source of the problem.

Comment: @jawad Ouch. That would take a while since it is a long intergrated process. If you could try sending the `test` variable to a Controller, that would be great.

Comment: What you posted is not XML.  If you have a working application then use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare the first request in working application with the c# that is not working.  Make the first request headers in c# look exactly like the working application.  If the server doesn't support xml than you will not get xml.

Comment: @jdweng Sir do you have any suggestion on how to achieve that? Currently I am just trying to send a string which is in XML format to c# using AJAX and getting a 500 error.

Comment: You are sending a request that is being rejected because server does not understand some of the contents.  The best way of solving these issues is to compare a working request with a non working request using a sniffer.  First find out the differences and then we can discuss how to modify the code.   The default request headers in c# are going to be different from your working JQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS you requested in the comments: I made simple controller and JS code to hit an `httppost` method within the controller using ajax:

1. The Controller Method:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SendXMLToS3(string json)
{
    return Json(new { Result = "PASS", Message = "testing SendXMLToS3" });
}
```

2. JS code:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myfunction() {

        var test = { "xmlString": "<nitf>...</nitf>" };
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "/Home/SendXMLToS3",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { "json": test },
            success: function (res) {
                alert(res.Message);
            },
            error: function (res) {
                //TODO: Add some code here for error handling or notifications
                alert("Not Done");
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

**Findings**:
The line `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` was causing the Internal 500 error, if you remove it, you should be fine.

Comment: Yes, that worked. Thanks a lot. Now I am able to send the string to the `Controller` and perform the required actions. Any idea on how to read the `blob` url string into the `Controller` method of c# ?

Comment: Regarding the blob url, please read the following explanation of blob urls: https://superuser.com/a/1109873/102549 in summary blob data can't be accessed at controller level directly "server side" it need to be rendered and exec first by JS engine.